# Calling function from current tab in a new tab

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code:

```
function challenge() {
    var body = $("body").html();
    if(body.match(/td\>([0-9]+)\<\/td\>/)[1] > 0){
        // find challengable player
        var url = body.match(/href="(\/game.php?.*challenge.*[0-9a-f]+)"/)[1].replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
        // open new tab with the link
        var winEvent = window.open(url, '_blank');
        // get random number between 7 and 10
        var rand = Math.random() * (10 - 7) + 7;
        // set interval for new tab to random minutes
        winEvent.setInterval(challenge, rand*1000);
        // close current tab
        window.close();
    }
}
window.setInterval(challenge, 5*1000);
```

In challenge() I look for a link and open it in a new tab. However, the following line is not working as intended:

```
winEvent.setInterval(challenge, rand*1000);
```

The new tab should call the challenge() function every rand seconds

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which same piece of JS? Can you elaborate?

Comment: changed the problem description

Comment: What is your intended purpose? what are you trying to do? that piece of code will work for current tab and not for the new one. If you want it to run on the new tab then you need to add that in the script or route or resolve of that route. A new tab will open from first tab and then another tab will open from second tab but what about the first tab?

Comment: from every new tab I would get another link that I have to again open in a new tab (the old one is closed). The infinite behaviour is intentional. I just don't see how I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on your comment and given code. I am still a lil confused. But from what I understood here that you want to open a new tab and in that new tab you want to open another new tab.

Here is a generic solution. You can change it according to your needs.

To test it in a fiddle you need to allow your popup blocker and ad blocker.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
    <script>
      function openTab() {
        var newWindow = window.open(); //CREATE A NEW TAB

        //WRITE CURRENT OUTER HTML TO THE NEW TAB (BASICALLY CLONING THE CURRENT TAB)
        newWindow.document
                 .write(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML)

        window.close();
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        openTab();
      }, 1000); //OPEN TAB AFTER 1 SECOND

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: This is not a good design or structure, as popup blockers or ad blockers will block your new tab opening. According to me, I wouldn't recommend doing something like this.**